# Can you melt chocolate chips on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food

Can you put chocolate chips close to the blech on Shabbat in hopes of melting them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [According to Halacha are you permitted to melt cheese on Shabbos?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67902/according-to-halacha-are-you-permitted-to-melt-cheese-on-shabbos)

Comment: @Ploni one difference - chocolate [melts](https://whatscookingamerica.net/ChocolateMelting.htm) at under Yad Soledes.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin According to many opinions so does chocolate.

Comment: @Ploni - another difference - this is chocolate. How is this a duplicate at all? Note especially the cheese-specific concerns raised in the other questions.

Comment: @Ploni I don't believe anyone says that chocolate melts at above Yad Soledes

Answer (score 4):

**It depends why you want to melt the chocolate chips.**

Chocolate is a special food in that it is already cooked (see [here](https://www.chocolatemonthclub.com/the-chocolate-making-process)) but turns into a semi-liquid once heated. The rule for dry solids that turn into liquids once heated (e.g., sugar, baby formula) is that they cannot be reheated above *yad soledet bo* (109-113 degrees F, 43-45 degrees C) because of the rule of *yesh bishul achar bishul bedavar lach* (see e.g., [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/163325/jewish/Bishul-Achar-Bishul-Cooking-After-Cooking.htm#footnoteRef4a163325))

As such one should avoid putting chocolate where it might go over that temperature. But as R Daniel Braude writes (Learn Shabbos, p. 139)

> **If** [...] **the liquid  will not reach 109/43 degrees** even if it will
>   stay there throughout Shabbos, **one may place it near a heat source**.
>   For instance, one may place a container of ice cream far enough from a
>   *blech* or covered hot plate that it will soften slightly and be easier to serve, yet will never reach 109/43 [degrees].

Now there is a question whether melting constitutes a prohibition of *molid* (creating a new entity). Shemirat Shabbat K'Hilchata (vol. 1, p. 99) writes one is allowed to melt ice cream so long as one does not place it where it could reach 113/54 degrees. Similarly one can freeze ice cream as it is generally thought of as food.

With chocolate, it might depend whether you are trying to create liquid chocolate (which might transgress *molid*) or looking to soften up the chocolate chips to create soft chocolate (which would be permitted according to the sources above).

Of course, [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).

Comment: Do you have a different or other evidence for your "might"-qualified claim that melting's permissibility depends on the purpose (rather than on the result)?

Comment: @msh210 I based it on SSK allowing to melt ice cream since the intent is not to create a liquid but softer ice cream which is easier to eat. Now the same ice cream, if left long enough, would turn into a liquid, so the SSK bases it on intent and "general thought as food" rather than purpose. I see the same is true for chocolate which is normally seen as a food, not a liquid.