# Can one char / sear a frankfurter on Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, cooking-bishul

I'm trying to get a better understanding of the general rule that "there is no cooking of already cooked foods".

Let's say a frankfurter has already been cooked (via boiling, etc.) If one puts the frank on the covered "blech" on the stove until it gets roasted and black, to me, it looks like it's being cooked more. Is blackening a frank or any other similar solid cooked food still permitted?

Comment: Roasting and boiling are different things.

Comment: http://etzion.org.il/he/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A8-7-%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%9C-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A8-%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%99%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%99%D7%94-%D7%90%D7%95-%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%9A

Comment: similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67902/759

Comment: @Loewian My Ivrit is good to a point. It looks like a thorough article on the subject. If possible, extract and translate the relevant points to create an answer.

Comment: note, cooking may not be the only issue here - charring is fairly likely going to come onto the issur of burning.

Answer (score -1):

It is forbidden. Even though there is "no cooking after cooking", that is only when the form of cooking is the same. But to go from boiling to roasting is forbidden

Comment: Welcoem to Mi Yodeya. Please provide a source to support this information. Offhand, I don't believe that this statement is universally correct. AFAIK, coffee is a permissible example of contradicting this statement. The beans are roasted. One adds hot water to it to make coffee.

Comment: Welcome to MY. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site.